# To replace integer by a string

Tags: java

The question is to  print the prime number series upto n.But if any of the primes contain the digit 7,it is replaced by S.
For example if n=7 the series will be
2 3 5 S 11 13 S
How will I do this?

Comment: why is there an S after 7?

Comment: your series what type of data is? array of int, string, ... ? your question is simply how to replace an integer with a string ? or to write a program that generates a prime numbers series from 1 to n and then replacing?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/java-program-to-display-prime-numbers/) is an example of how to find and print prime numbers. After that all you have to do is check each number for the digit 7 and replace.

In the code give on the site this could be done using a simple string contains method.

```
if (counter == 2)
  {
     if (Integer.toString(i).contains("7"){
       primeNumbers = primeNumbers + "S" + " ";
     }
     else {
       //Appended the Prime number to the String
       primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the optimal way but should work. Function to test if it prime:

```
private boolean isPrime(int n) 
{
    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And a code to execute main loop:

```
  for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++)
        {
            if(isPrime(i)) 
            {
                if(Integer.valueOf(i).toString().contains("7")) {
                   System.out.print("S ");
                } else  {
                  System.out.print(i + " ");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your series is contained into an array of int, then convert it into a `String`:

```
int[] arPrimes = {2,3,5,7,11,13,17, ... }; //generate your prime numbers series

String strPrimes = Arrays.toString(array);
```

then, you should have this sequence:

```
strPrimes = "2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ... ";
```

you just have to replace substrings that contains `"7"` with `"S"`;

```
String strPrimes7S = strPrime.replaceAll(",([0-9]*7+[0-9]*)", ",S");
```